# Language issue accessing desktop with batch?

Tags: batch-file, desktop

Im trying to access the desktop with a batch file thats reletivly easy (see following code)

```
c:\%userprofile%\desktop
```

Okay but I dont live in an english speaking country so the code is as follows

```
c:\%userprofile%\bureaublad
```

My question is thus, is there aything uninversal between the two languages I can use, as id like to keep things as uniformed as possible (dont want two languages criss-crossing through eachother)

Comment: check from regedit if there's something set in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\LanguageConfiguration`

Comment: another thing you can try is `explorer.exe /e,::{04731B67-D933-450a-90E6-4ACD2E9408FE}` but I'm not sure if this is helps you

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can get the value from the registry but I don't have another version of windows to test with. Type this at a `CMD` prompt and see if it returns the value you're looking for:

```
 reg query "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders"
```

If so, it's just a matter of extracting the 3rd token in a `FOR` loop to use for your desktop parameter.